# Buenas , duda de noob numeros reales

Tags: c

Buenas quería preguntar como, después de haber efectuado operaciones con numeros reales , por ejemplo 100 - 1.5 = 98.5 ;

Como podría quedarme solo con el 98 ?

Comment: Haz un *cast* a int: `double d= 1.5; int i = (int) d;`

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma facil es usar una funcion de redondeo.

En el lenguaje C, debes incluir la libreria `math.h` y la sintaxis es `round(x)`

Comment: muchas gracias , soy nuevo y ando un poco perdido jajaja, podrías decirme algún libro o algún curso sobre C para aprender mas ?

Answer (score -1):

Podrias tomar el valor y hacer un split por punto en la primera posición te quedará el 98 y en la segunda el 5.

Otra opción es convertir el resultado a número entero:

Ejemplo:
En java

```
int valor1=100;
Double valor2 =1.5;
int valor=(int) (valor1-valor2);

System.out.println(valor);
```

Resultado:
98

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta. Las mismas, tienen que ser en el mismo lenguaje en el cual se pregunto. mira por favor [answer], y de paso hace el [tour]